# Why does my Spark Structured Streaming job not write to JDBC in batches?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, mariadb, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Spark Structured streaming job that reads from a source Kafka topic and writes to two sinks using [forEachBatch](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#foreachbatch).

- Destination Kafka Topic
- JDBC sink (MariaDB) table

Here is some pseudo code for additional context:

```py
def write_to_kafka_and_maria(df, epoch_id):
    df.persist()

    df=df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")

    df.write \
      .format("kafka") \
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2") \
      .option("topic", "target_topic") \
      .save()

    df.write \
      .format("jdbc") \
      .options(
        url="jdbc:mysql:dbserver:port/db",
        driver="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver",
        dbtable="tablename",
        user="username",
        password="password",
        batchSize=100000,
        numPartition=10
      ).mode("append") \
      .save()
     
     df.unpersist()

# Read from the topic
df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2") \
  .option("subscribe", "source_topic") \
  .load()

# Write to Kafka and MariaDB
write = df.writeStream.trigger(once=True).foreachBatch(write_to_kafka_and_maria).start()

write.awaitTermination()
```

When I run my job, I can see my records arrive at my destination Kafka at a rate of about 7-8k records second. However, I do not see my records arrive in MariaDB until near the end of the job. In addition, the write to MariaDB is not performed immediately after the write to Kafka. Instead, the write to MariaDB occurs 10-12 minutes after writing to the destination topic is complete. Is this expected behaviour, or should I see the records propagate to both sinks in batches one after another (since that is what the [forEachBatch](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#foreachbatch) operation is meant for)? It seems like the job reads the data from the source Kafka topic twice and performs different operations under the hood before writing to Kafka vs. MariaDB. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need to write to Kafka? Seems like this example isn't modifying any data from the source (other than serialization)

Comment: Yes, I removed the ETL logic between the read and the write to isolate this issue. I am performing some transformations to the data before writing to the sinks (Kafka & MariaDB).

Comment: How many executors got launched? If you open the Spark UI and look at the DAG, what does it show in terms of execution order?

Comment: 3 executors get launched (5 cores each). The source Kafka topic has 4 partitions. The Spark UI shows two stages: one for the write to Kafka (save at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) and a second for the write to Maria (save at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0). We also just looked at the logs and it seems the second stage is reading from Kafka again.

Comment: As I understand the `batchsize` option in the jdbc sink waits until it can save 100000 rows into the jdbc table. Have you tried reducing/adjusting it?

Comment: Dont specify the batch size or set the batch size to df length